# Bug or feature: I can't vote to close a question a second time

Tags: support, status-bydesign, closing

I voted to close [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/372545/are-there-games-that-focus-on-realistic-basic-need-provisions-in-pre-industrial) since it is asking for game recommendations. However, I also wanted to leave a comment linking the asker to suggestions for sites that allow recommendations. I wanted to use the link that was in the dialog I saw when I was voting to close, so I retracted my vote so I could revote to close and copy that link. However, I can't revote to close because I have already voted to close.

Should the site have "forgotten" about my first close vote since I retracted my vote? Or do we intentionally not allow people to "vote to close -> retract -> vote to close again"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This is intended**. Once you retract a close vote, you cannot cast another vote to close. See [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167514/214193) from when close vote retraction was originally implemented.

Comment: It also says that you can revote again after the retraction ages away. Can you confirm that please?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 That should be correct, but doesn't usually come up. That just means that a retracted close vote can be cast again after close votes expire, the same way a cast close vote can be cast again after votes expire. Close votes expire after 14 days.